# Found 2 versions of android-v4 jar in dependency list

Tags: android, facebook

hii
I have integrated facebook in android. and now when i click on  the fb button i get this error.

```
          Found 2 versions of android-support-v4.jar in the dependency list,
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are adding more than one library project to your project, and these projects requires android support 4 library. then make sure that all of these projects use the same android support library (The newest). So, get the latest version of the library and copy it to the lib folder of your projects.

Answer (score 0):

Try to delete the extra android-support-v4.jar library from libs folder.

Answer (score 0):

Go to libs in project by going to windows explorer and delete the support file in libs.
Now go to workspace and open the appcompat folder copy the v4 file and paste in Yourprojectname>libs

Now goto eclipse and clean the project and restart eclipse 
all errors will be gone.